# How to move scrollbars automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Steps

1. Get remote data using ajax (jQuery)
2. I Load the data into div with style overflow:auto

When I view the page the data is still getting loaded. The scrollbar does not move till the end of the page .

How do I move the scrollbar automatically so that the latest data is seen on the web page.

Is this possible in Jquery?Please let me know .

Mithun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a scrollTo plugin.

Check it out here: [jQuery scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: there's also a vanilla JS scrollTo method.

Comment: ..which doesn't take an DOM/jQuery element as argument.